# Rendering into multiple views with Metal

Tags: gpu, metal, metalkit

I have successfully used Metal to render into a simple view, and update at full FPS, by following and modifying the code at https://github.com/jim-ec/metal-hello-triangle

[image]

I am now trying to repeat the process by drawing into multiple views in an NSCollectionView.

[image]

My render code is as follows, where each view in the NSCollectionView has a global `Renderer` object as its delegate:

```
class Renderer {

/// Initialisation as per the linked tutorial

public func draw(in view: MTKView)
{
    let dataSize     = VERTEX_DATA.count * MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: VERTEX_DATA[0])
    VERTEX_DATA[1][1] = Float(arc4random_uniform(100)) / 100
    let vertexBuffer = view.device?.makeBuffer(bytes:   VERTEX_DATA,
                                              length:  dataSize,
                                              options: [])

    let commandBuffer  = mCommandQueue.makeCommandBuffer()!

    let commandEncoder = commandBuffer.makeRenderCommandEncoder(descriptor: view.currentRenderPassDescriptor!)
    commandEncoder?.setRenderPipelineState(mPipeline)
    commandEncoder?.setVertexBuffer(vertexBuffer, offset: 0, index: 0)
    commandEncoder?.drawPrimitives(type: .triangle,
                                 vertexStart: 0,
                                 vertexCount: 3,
                                 instanceCount: 1)
    commandEncoder?.endEncoding()

    commandBuffer.present(view.currentDrawable!)
    commandBuffer.commit()
    commandBuffer.waitUntilCompleted()
}

}
```

The `arc4random_uniform` call is to make the triangles change colour, so I can confirm that they are redrawing.

Unfortunately, views only update around 3 times a second, and not at all in sync. Looking at instruments, the GPU is barely breaking a sweat, and the CPU overhead of both WindowServer and my app are pretty huge. The `draw` function is now very heavy with `makeRenderCommandEncoder` becoming a real bottleneck, and there are obviously some synchronisation issues given the sporadic updating.

I expected this to be more-or-less similar performance as I'm still doing a trivial amount of drawing, but it really isn't. What am I doing wrong?

Working example available at https://github.com/SirWhiteHat/MetalPerformanceProblem

Thank you!

Comment: There is not enough code here to deduce anything tbh.

Comment: @Spo1ler is there anything you’d recommend I add to make it clearer? Apart from this, I have the initialisation code as detailed in the link and an AppDelegate, nothing else.

Comment: in the example you linked, there's `waitUntilCompleted`, do you have `waitUntilCompleted` somewhere?

Comment: @Spo1ler I do now ;) good spot! But unfortunately to no avail, same issue. I will add the initialisation code for completeness.

Comment: More code would be insightful, or better yet a minimum reproducible project. I would suggest looking at what is using up the CPU. arc4random is pretty expensive IIRC, and if you are running 30 of them 30-60 times per second could be part of the problem.

Comment: @JeshuaLacock happy to produce a full example on GitHub. For all intents and purposes, this _is_ the code apart from the simplest boilerplate.

Comment: I tried the GitHub code and it works fine, so clearly it must be something else which we don't have to look at.

Comment: @JeshuaLacock I have published the whole code at https://github.com/SirWhiteHat/MetalPerformanceProblem

Comment: Works fine here. Metal capture reports 120fps.

Comment: I see you are adding 100 items, so at 120fps that would be 12,000 arc4random calls per second. I still suspect that is the issue. What type of Mac are you using? Note that I don't see any arc4random calls in the sample project.

Comment: @JeshuaLacock I took them out of the sample project just in case it was that (and for me the problem persists). Looking at it in instruments, it’s the calls to the metal API that take all the time, not arc4random. Are you on apple silicon by chance?

Comment: I ask as I’m on Intel, and I wonder if the bottleneck is calls/rendered views going between CPU and GPU, where on AS it’s all fused in one chip.

Comment: I'm on a M1 Mac. Yeah, binding is expensive as Metal is a state machine. 100 instances running at 120fps would be a lot of overhead. I'd try to first set the `preferredFramesPerSecond` property of your `MTKView` to 24 or 30. If its still choppy, I'd suggest lowering the number of items until it runs smoothly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256498/discussion-between-oliver-hawker-and-jeshua-lacock).

Comment: @JeshuaLacock I can definitely lower the frame rate, but lowering the number of items is going to be a problem (in reality, I’m going to need >500 of the things!). Is there a concept of rendering into one big view/layer in one go and showing a slice of it in each view? And what stage are you referring to with “binding”?

Comment: On older machines, I suspect it won't be possible to run 500 instances at 24+ fps. Rendering one and splitting would certainly help, but creating 500 tiles 24+ fps seems problematic as well. By binding I mean setting each buffer etc. Speaking of which, it would help to create the buffers once per view and reuse. It might make more sense to render to images instead of MTKViews and only show images for visible cells.

Comment: I’ve moved this to chat :)